# Existence of a map $\phi \colon \mathbb N\cup \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb N\cup \{0\}$ that holds the property $\phi (ab) = \phi(a)+ \phi(b)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Does  there  exist  a  map $\phi \colon \mathbb N\cup \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb N\cup \{0\}$  that  holds  the  following  property?
 $$\phi (ab) = \phi(a)+ \phi(b)$$
 If  they  do  what  do  they  look  like$?$
 Here $\mathbb N$ is  the  set  of  all  natural  numbers  and  addition  and  multiplication  are   usual  for  integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You require $\phi(0)=\phi(0\cdot n)=\phi(0)+\phi(n)$, hence $\phi(n)=0$ for all $n$.

---

There are more if you consider $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N_0$ instead:
For each prime $p$ pick an element $c_p\in\mathbb N_0$. Then for
$$ n=\prod_pp^{a_p}$$let
$$ \phi(n)=\sum_p a_pc_p$$

Comment: So  that  means If  I  consider  the  domain with  $0$  I  get  only  one  such  map  but  without  $0$ ,  I  can  construct  as  many  as  I  want  with  different  $c_{p}$ for  $p$.

Comment: @user118494 when you say"as many as I want" you may wish to be careful. This technique generates an infinite family of such map, but the family is countably infinite, not uncountable.

Comment: @Se18 But after all there are as many such maps as there are arbitrary maps $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N_0$. By the way these are contiunuum-many, not countable